# Graphicsmagick convert not replacing %d

Tags: graphicsmagick

I am trying to use a convert function to convert a pdf to series of images with following command:

```
convert -density 200 AccurioPress_20C6100_20C6085_20datasheet_BD_300dpi.pdf -thumbnail 70x100 -type TrueColor -page +0+0 thumbnails/AccurioPress_20C6100_20C6085_20datasheet_BD_300dpi-%d.jpg
```

The problem is, that I am getting a single image with name: AccurioPress_20C6100_20C6085_20datasheet_BD_300dpi-**%d**.jpg

Does somebody know why the **%d** is not replaced with a number?

I use GraphicsMagick 1.3.18

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try inserting `+adjoin` just before the output file:

```
gm convert ... +adjoin output-%d.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped.

Comment: It's weird that +adjoin was required, since jpg is a single-image format.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson I agree, but I tried it, it was necessary and it did the trick :-)

Comment: It turns out to be a design decision in GraphicsMagick, to require the +adjoin flag in such cases, because files may legitimately have "%d" in their names